# LTspice: is there a simple way to make pulse voltage source resettable?

Tags: ltspice, generator, pulse

I have a circuit in which I have to have a retriggerable one-shot pulse generator. The trigger event is an edge from a comparator. After the edge, a single positive pulse should be generated, duration given in (n)seconds. I'm aware that this task can be realized with a complicated mixed-signal circuit (like building a complete controller from discrete parts), but perhaps there is a simple and easy way?

Comment: Are you already trying PWL() to generate that initial single pulse?

Comment: Why would the PWL be different from a usual pulse generator? PWL does not make the generator triggerable

Comment: No, it's not triggerable. That's why I was asking what you were using for the initial pulse. You can make a .SUBCKT that will do what you want, though. Look at the sw part, to start.

Answer (score 3):

There are three methods I can think of now: one method is to use the `trigger` keyword for the voltage source, another is to use the `dflop`, and the other one is to use two `AND` gates:

[image: test]

`V(ctl)` is randomly chosen as the controlling voltage.

The `trigger` solution seems to transform the voltage source into a behavioural source, internally, because the edges are affected and the time resolution can suffet (e.g. try with `ton=100n` and no pulses will be seen). Imposing a tighter timestep can overcome this limitation. The advantage is that the pulse comes exactly on time.

The `dflop` is used here as a self-resettable latch, with `td` setting the pulse width. The advantage is that you can use the temporal helpers, `tau` and `tripdt` to get very nice edges, but the disadvantage is that the pulse will come delayed by `td`.

I'd recommend the third solution, which has the advantages of both of the two previous examples, and two gates are hardly an encumbrance. `A2` is really an inverter, so it can be replaced if it doesn't suit you.

Comment: Always enjoy your contributions with LTspice! +1 of course.

Answer (score 0):

LTSPICE doesn't have a primitive element to do this. You will need to design a circuit that does what you want.